# upgrading phpmyadmin on local development server

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp, upgrade

Using XAMPP on windows 7.

Can we upgrade

> phpmyadmin

on local development server with out upgrading MySQl.

Answer (score 1):

You can read about [how to upgrade phpMyAdmin](http://wiki.phpmyadmin.net/pma/Upgrading). Be aware that if you do this, if you later upgrade XAMPP, you may walk over the version of phpMyAdmin you just installed. So backup the database just in case.

Comment: I'd install phpMyAdmin to your web root folder. Note that the folder name will have to be different from the XAMPP path otherwise they'll conflict. Also, if you only upgrade phpMyAdmin, there should be no risk to your database (I still recommend a backup, but just to be thorough).